# Prove "rev (rev l) = l" in Coq

Tags: coq, induction

This is one of the exercise given to me, I got stuck almost immediately after doing an induction on l. I dont know what other assertion to make here.

I'm not allowed to use advanced tactics like auto, intuition etc.

```
Fixpoint snoc {A : Type} l a : list A :=

match l with

  | nil    => a :: nil

  | h :: t => h :: (snoc t a)

end.

Fixpoint rev {A : Type} l : list A :=

match l with

  | nil    => nil

  | h :: t => snoc (rev t) h

end.

(Prove the following)

Theorem rev_rev : forall A (l : list A),

rev (rev l) = l.
```

Comment: How would you prove this theorem using pen & paper? If you have no idea how the proof goes, it's going to be hard to formalise it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have all been new to this, and in the beginning it is useful to get help to not get stuck an lose courage when trying to master a new subject.  I'll try to give you a hint without giving away too much.

The reason why this is trickier than earlier exercises may be because this proof involves doing two inductive reasoning steps.  You probably did the first one just fine and got the second goal like

```
  ...
  IHl : rev (rev l) = l
  ============================
   rev (snoc (rev l) a) = a :: l
```

Unfortunately you can't use your inductive hypothesis `IHl` immediately, because the argument to `rev` is not in the right shape.

So, here you could try to prove *another* lemma about `rev (snoc l a) = ...` that would turn the goal into something which you could rewrite with `IHl`.
If you can figure that out, and prove that in a lemma, then you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you larsr , I did it, rev (snoc l a) = a :: rev l. So as you can probably tell, I'm quite new to this logic thing. You sound like a decent guy, seeing you're the only one who offered some help, I was wondering if you could share some general tips and maybe some experience of yours when doing Induction.

Answer (score 1):

We won't do your homework for you, you should first prove it on pen & paper as @gallais said.

A tip: you might need to generalize your property a little (use an intermediate lemma) to be able to prove `rev_rev`. You should have a look at `rev_append`.

Comment: like I mention, I need help not answers. so perhaps you could be a little bit more specific bout your tip ? I'm speculating you are referring to something like 'since the double rev doesnt do anything, I could generalize l a little by saying a : : rev (l) instead of just l'

Comment: even using ``++`` instead of ``::``. Larsr tips is a good one too :)